# Print input values in multiplaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current code prints out the value of whatever I type inside the input, but then I wish for it to be able to show the result in multiple places on the same page.

Here is my JS:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#airlines_name').keyup(function() {
        $('#name_airlines').html($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

and here is the how it prints

```html
<span id="name_airlines"></span>
```

I wish the above span to be used in many places on the same page and show the textbox typed value.

Comment: you can use `class` instead of `id`. `$('.name_airlines').html($(this).val());`

Comment: Thanks for guiding me out it works now :)